# Remove URLs from string

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a vector of strings—`myStrings`—in R that look something like:

```
[1] download file from `http://example.com`
[2] this is the link to my website `another url`
[3] go to `another url` from more info.
```

where `another url` is a valid http url but stackoverflow will not let me insert more than one url thats why i'm writing `another url` instead. I want to remove all the urls from `myStrings` to look like:

```
[1] download file from
[2] this is the link to my website
[3] go to from more info.
```

I've tried many functions in the `stringr` package but nothing works.

Comment: Can you list your code for a few of the things you've tried? And do all the URLs start with `http://`?

Comment: `gsub(" http.*","",myStrings)` will work for you?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Hi David this works too very straightforward thanks very much!!

Comment: @maryan,. Can I put that as an answer

Comment: @ssdecontrol David & Akrun have solved my problem thanks for your input!

Comment: David answer is wrong since it remove every character after `http`. It means if you have sentence such as : `my url is http://one.com or could be http://two.com`; the result will be `my url is ` instead of `my url is or could be `

Answer (score 18):

You can use `gsub` with a regular expression to match URLs,

Set up a vector:

```
x <- c(
    "download file from http://example.com", 
    "this is the link to my website http://example.com", 
    "go to http://example.com from more info.",
    "Another url ftp://www.example.com",
    "And https://www.example.net"
)
```

Remove all the URLs from each string:

```
gsub(" ?(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+", "", x)
# [1] "download file from"             "this is the link to my website"
# [3] "go to from more info."          "Another url"                   
# [5] "And"
```

**Update:** It would be best if you could post a few different URLs so we know what we're working with.  But I think this regular expression will work for the URLs you mentioned in the comments:

```
" ?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[.|/](.*)"
```

The above expression explained:

- `?` optional space
- `(f|ht)` match `"f"` or `"ht"`
- `tp` match `"tp"`
- `(s?)` optionally match `"s"` if it's there
- `(://)` match `"://"`
- `(.*)` match every character (everything) up to
- `[.|/]` a period or a forward-slash
- `(.*)` then everything after that

I'm not an expert with regular expressions, but I think I explained that correctly.

Note: url shorteners are no longer allowed in SO answers, so I was forced to remove a section while making my most recent edit.  See edit history for that part.

Comment: regex "((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)"

Comment: Really, it removes the URLs on my end.  What do your URLs look like exactly?  You can put them in quotes the original question.

Comment: Give this one a try `gsub("(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[.][a-z]{2,6}", "", x)`

Comment: @RichardScriven I still get this result /N1kq0F26tG  for urls such as this http://t.co/N1kq0F26tG

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: I tried the above regex in regex101 and it also removed the rest of the text after the url ends.

Answer (score 10):

I've been working on a canned group of regular expressions for common tasks like this that I've thrown into a package, [qdapRegex, on github](https://github.com/trinker/qdapRegex) that will eventually go to CRAN.  It can also extract the pieces as well as sub them out.  Feedback on the package for any taking a look is welcomed.

Here it is:

```
library (devtools)
install_github("trinker/qdapRegex")
library(qdapRegex)

x <- c("download file from http://example.com", 
         "this is the link to my website http://example.com", 
         "go to http://example.com from more info.",
         "Another url ftp://www.example.com",
         "And https://www.example.net",
         "twitter type: t.co/N1kq0F26tG",
         "still another one https://t.co/N1kq0F26tG :-)")

rm_url(x, pattern=pastex("@rm_twitter_url", "@rm_url"))

## [1] "download file from"             "this is the link to my website"
## [3] "go to from more info."          "Another url"                   
## [5] "And"                            "twitter type:"                 
## [7] "still another one :-)"         

rm_url(x, pattern=pastex("@rm_twitter_url", "@rm_url"), extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "http://example.com"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "http://example.com"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "http://example.com"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "ftp://www.example.com"
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] "https://www.example.net"
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] "t.co/N1kq0F26tG"
## 
## [[7]]
## [1] "https://t.co/N1kq0F26tG"
```

**Edit** I saw that twitter links were not removed.  I will not be adding this to the regex specific to the `rm_url` function but have added it to the dictionary in `qdapRegex`.  So there's no specific function to remove standard urls and twitter both but the `pastex` (paste regular expression) allows you to easily grab regexes from the dictionary and past them together (using the pipe operator, `|`).  Since all `rm_XXX` style functions work essentially the same you can pass the `pastex` output to the `pattern` argument of any `rm_XXX` function or create your own function as I show below:

```
rm_twitter_url <- rm_(pattern=pastex("@rm_twitter_url", "@rm_url"))
rm_twitter_url(x)
rm_twitter_url(x, extract=TRUE)
```

Comment: @TylerRinker OMG it works amazing but it didn't remove this url http://t.co/yz8nUKagEH

Comment: I added the ability to remove twitter links to the package.  See answer for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

```
 str1 <- c("download file from http://example.com", "this is the link to my website https://www.google.com/ for more info")

 gsub('http\\S+\\s*',"", str1)
 #[1] "download file from "                         
 #[2] "this is the link to my website for more info"

 library(stringr)
 str_trim(gsub('http\\S+\\s*',"", str1)) #removes trailing/leading spaces
 #[1] "download file from"                          
 #[2] "this is the link to my website for more info"
```

#### Update

In order to match `ftp`, I would use the same idea from @Richard Scriven's post

```
  str1 <- c("download file from http://example.com", "this is the link to my website https://www.google.com/ for more info",
  "this link to ftp://www.example.org/community/mail/view.php?f=db/6463 gives more info")


  gsub('(f|ht)tp\\S+\\s*',"", str1)
  #[1] "download file from "                         
  #[2] "this is the link to my website for more info"
  #[3] "this link to gives more info"
```

Answer (score 2):

Some previous answers remove beyond the end of the URL and the "\b" extension would help.  It could cover also the "sftp://" urls.

For regular urls:

```
gsub("(s?)(f|ht)tp(s?)://\\S+\\b", "", x)
```

For tiny urls:

```
gsub("[A-Za-z]{1,5}[.][A-Za-z]{2,3}/[A-Za-z0-9]+\\b", "", x)
```